# How to extract hours from datetime in a pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a `pyspark` dataframe like the following:

```
df.show(5)

+----------+
|   t_start|
+----------+
|1506125172|
|1506488793|
|1506242331|
|1506307472|
|1505613973|
+----------+
```

I would like to get the hour and the day of each unix timestamp. This what I am doing:

```
df = df.withColumn("datetime", F.from_unixtime("t_start", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"))
df = df.withColumn("hour", F.date_trunc('hour',F.to_timestamp("datetime","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")))
df.show(5)

+----------+-------------------+----+
|   t_start|           datetime|hour|
+----------+-------------------+----+
|1506125172|23/09/2017 00:06:12|null|
|1506488793|27/09/2017 05:06:33|null|
|1506242331|24/09/2017 08:38:51|null|
|1506307472|25/09/2017 02:44:32|null|
|1505613973|17/09/2017 02:06:13|null|
+----------+-------------------+----+
```

And I got `null` in the column `hour`

Comment: does this help ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46779993/creating-datetime-from-string-column-in-pyspark

Comment: >>> df = spark.createDataFrame([('2015-04-08 13:08:15',)], ['a'])
>>> df.select(hour('a').alias('hour')).collect()
[Row(hour=13)]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `hour` function with `from_unixtime` simply.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df.withColumn('hour', hour(from_unixtime('t_start'))).show()

+----------+----+
|   t_start|hour|
+----------+----+
|1506125172|   0|
|1506488793|   5|
|1506242331|   8|
|1506307472|   2|
|1505613973|   2|
+----------+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `hour()` function to extract the hour unit from a timestamp column. (Also, change your date format. It is in `dd/MM/yyyy`)

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn("hour", hour(F.to_timestamp("datetime","dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"))).show()
+----------+-------------------+----+
|   t_start|           datetime|hour|
+----------+-------------------+----+
|1506125172|23/09/2017 00:06:12|   0|
|1506488793|27/09/2017 05:06:33|   5|
|1506242331|24/09/2017 08:38:51|   8|
|1506307472|25/09/2017 02:44:32|   2|
|1505613973|17/09/2017 02:06:13|   2|
+----------+-------------------+----+
```